# collapsing bottom bar with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a fixed bottom bar that can be collapsed on scroll, and right now to collapse it down I use :

```
$(".Bar").animate({
  height: 0
}, 700);

$(".Bar").animate({
  height: originalBuyBarHeight
}, 700);
```

So I change his height, which looks not good.
How would I simply *slide it down outside of the screen*(with all its content), then **slide it up back to the original position** ?

CSS:

```
.Bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12vh;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change the bottom value

```
$(".Bar").animate({
          bottom: 0
      }, 700);



$(".Bar").animate({
          bottom: '-12vh'
      }, 700);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a class and achieve this effect with CSS:

```
.bar {
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(0);
    transition: transform .7s ease-in-out; /* you can change the time and easing */
}

.bar.moveOffscreen {
    transform: translateY(110%);
}
```

And apply it with JS, instead of your original code:

```
/* code to hide it */
$(".bar").addClass('moveOffscreen');
/* code to reveal it */
$(".bar").removeClass('moveOffscreen');
```

Achieve this with vanilla JS, without JQuery:

```
/* code to hide it */
document.getElementById(".bar").classList.add('moveOffscreen');
/* code to reveal it */
document.getElementById(".bar").classList.remove('moveOffscreen');
```

PS: don't use capital letters at the start of your class names => Change **.Bar** to **.bar**